# My ubuntu server got too many connections and cost all the bandwidth…

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ddos

I have closed all my services, my ufw firewall only allows 443 and 80 port but there're still a LOT of different IPs with different ports connecting to my server and costing my server's bandwidth. I'm afraid my server is under attack by someone. Could someone help me? Thanks.

[image: The status checked by iftop -P, bandwith is 2MB]

Comment: I see one ssh connection (presumably yours) and some regular connections to https. The random high numbers are the source ports, which is normal. Nothing suspicious to see there.

Comment: You could analyze the access logs of your server to figure out what the connections are requesting. I once was stumped that according to my providers statistics one of my servers accumulated multiple hundreds of gigabytes of traffic in a short time. Turned out that I forgot to delete a video of a game from the server, someone found it and posted the URL in a forum.

Comment: yeah, I exactly know what are requesting, the problem is that the the attacker simulated like 2000 fake users requesting one api at the same time which cost almost all the bandwidth and lead to no responding to other real users. The fake users are from 2000 different ips requesting in very normal frequency (rates), so I can't ban the ip with fail2ban depending on the high rates. For now, I just banned the attackers ips with ip subnet mask. And I know it's not the best way to solve it. Orz...